# Angular 6 timer issue

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, rxjs

I have a view which polls an endpoint every 30 seconds and updates if there are changes. In the same view I have a div which is shown/hidden every 7 seconds. The timers are started at the same time.

The first few times it runs, it runs perfectly. It's not until the first 30s timer polls again that it basically starts flickering back and forward every 2 seconds - which it shouldn't.

component.ts

```
  getScreen(tapCode) {
    timer(0, 30000)
      .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.dataService.get_screen(tapCode)))
      .subscribe(objectResp => {
        this.callResp = objectResp.status;
        this.polledObj = objectResp.items;
        this.landing = false;
        this.loaded = true;
        this.unavailable = objectResp.items.unavailable;
        localStorage.setItem('ontapCode', tapCode);
        this.getAds(this.polledObj);
      });
  }

  getAds(polledObj) {
    this.showAd = false;
    this.adTimer = timer(0, 7000);
    this.adSubscription = this.adTimer.subscribe(() => {
      if(this.timerCount >= this.polledObj.adverts.length) {
        this.timerCount = 0;
      }
      if(this.timerCount <= this.polledObj.adverts.length) {
        this.adImage = this.polledObj.adverts[this.timerCount].filename;
        this.timerCount++;
      }
      this.showAd = !this.showAd;
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
   <div *ngIf="callResp === 'OK'" class="tap">
      <div *ngIf="unavailable === '1' || unavailable === 1" class="object-unavailable">
        <img src="./assets/unavailable.png" class="unavailable-img">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="unavailable === '0' || unavailable === 0">
        <img src={{polledObj.img}} class="img-object">
        <div class="container">
          <div *ngIf="showAd === true">
            <div class="advertisement">
              <img src={{adImage}}" class="img-ad">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="showAd === false">
              <div class="object-detail-container">
                <h3 (click)="resetStorage()" class="object-name text-white">{{polledObj.object_name}}</h3>
                <h4 class="text-white object-brewery">{{polledObj.brewery}}</h4>
                <h4 class="text-white object-style">{{polledObj.style}} - {{polledObj.abv}}%</h4>
                <div class="object-sizes" *ngFor="let size of polledObj.sizes">
                  <span class="object-size-name">{{size.name}}: </span>
                  <span class="object-size-volume"> {{size.volume*1000}}ml </span>
                  <span class="object-size-price"> ${{getPrice(size.price)}} </span>
                  <span class="object-size-std"> {{getSizeStd(size)}} </span>
                  <span class="object-size-std-drinks"> std drinks</span>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Every time `timer(0, 30000)` emits you're creating a new `timer(0, 7000)` so after 30s you have two different `timer(0, 7000)` timers doing the same thing. Maybe you just wanted to emit once after 30s so you can use `timer(7000)`. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer

Comment: I ended up condensing the two timers into one and it solved the problem. I still do get an issue where if I've not had the window open, the view will basically flicker for a few seconds but that's it.